# Assign int value to JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, integer, boolean

Im trying to set a value to five different JCheckbox's but having a little trouble doing so.
I have set the checkbox's to a boolean type data within the main class before any methods:

```
 boolean s1 = solarPanel.isSelected();
 boolean s2 = ducted.isSelected();
 boolean s3 = homeTheatre.isSelected();
 boolean s4 = spa.isSelected();
 boolean s5 = swimming.isSelected();
```

Now im trying to assign an int value to each of the checkbox through the function:

```
private void options()
{ 
    if (s1 == true){
        s1 = 7500;
    } 
    if (s2 == true){
        s2 = 5000;
    } 
    if (s3 == true){
        s3 = 8000;
    } 
    if (s4 == true){
        s4 = 3500;
    } 
    if (s5 == true){
        s5 = 12000;
    } 
}
```

But getting an 'incompatible types' error. From here I will be calling the 'options' function within another function so a final price can be calculated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Curious...why not just pass an array of booleans, where each element represents the value of one of the check boxes...?

Comment: *"Im trying to set a value to five different JCheckbox's"*  By 'set' DYM that only one should be selectable at a time?  If so, I'd recommend to look at `JRadioButton` and `ButtonGroup` or better `JComboBox` or single selection `JList` showing a custom object (e.g. with attributes `productName` and `energyConsumption`) using a custom cell renderer.

Comment: How would I go about that @MadProgrammer?
@AndrewThompson no I need to have the user be able to select multiple at any one time or none at all.

Comment: You have five values, create a `boolean` array of `5` (`boolean[] options = new boolean[5];`, then for each option, set it's corresponding element in the `options` array...

Comment: Still a little confused...
'private void options()
    {
        boolean[] options = new boolean[5];
        options[0] = 7500;
        options[1] = 5000;
        options[2] = 8000;
        options[3] = 3500;
        options[4] = 12000;
    }'
Like so? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Still the same problem as before, `int` is not `boolean`.  Why do you need to convert the values in the first place?

Comment: I need to convert the values so that when a JCheckbox is selected I can add that value can be added on to another value to give a final value(price in my instance) So what I'm trying to get at is that a house price is 275000 and one of the checkbox options is a swimming pool extra for 12000, so I want to add that 12000 to the 275000 to get my final price. If that makes sense. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Then I would create an `int` array, which corresponds to the each `JCheckBox`, `int[] values = new int[]{7500, 5000, 8000, 3500, 12000}`, then place each `JCheckBox` into an array `JCheckBox[] selections = new JCheckBox[]{solarPanel, ducted, homeTheatre, spa, swimming};`, now it's a simply matter to create a `for-next-loop` and simply compare the `selections[i].isSelected()`, when true, add the value from `options[i]` to your tally...

Answer (score 3):

Consider this alternate approach where we are dealing with a group of objects in the form of a `Product` that has attributes `productName` & `energyConsumption` displayed in a `JList` using a custom cell renderer.

[image]

### Output

```
User Selected:
Product name: Ducted Heating  power consumption: 5000
Product name: Home Theater  power consumption: 8000
Product name: Heated Pool  power consumption: 12000
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ProductSelector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Product[] products = {
            new Product("None", 0),
            new Product("Ducted Heating", 5000),
            new Product("Home Theater", 8000),
            new Product("Heated Spa", 3500),
            new Product("Heated Pool", 12000)
        };
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JList list = new JList(products);
                list.setVisibleRowCount(products.length);
                list.setCellRenderer(new ProductCellRenderer(30));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list));
                java.util.List selected = list.getSelectedValuesList();
                ListIterator li = selected.listIterator();
                System.out.println("User Selected:");
                while (li.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(li.next());
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class ProductCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    int scale;

    ProductCellRenderer(int scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (c instanceof JLabel && value instanceof Product) {
            JLabel l = (JLabel) c;
            Product product = (Product) value;
            l.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
            l.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            int width = product.getPowerConsumption() / scale;
            int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
            if (width > 0) {
                BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        width,
                        16,
                        type);
                l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
            }
            l.setText(product.getProductName());
        }
        return c;
    }
}

class Product {

    private String productName;
    private int powerConsumption;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String productName, int powerConsumption) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.powerConsumption = powerConsumption;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productName
     */
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    /**
     * @param productName the productName to set
     */
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the powerConsumption
     */
    public int getPowerConsumption() {
        return powerConsumption;
    }

    /**
     * @param powerConsumption the powerConsumption to set
     */
    public void setPowerConsumption(int powerConsumption) {
        this.powerConsumption = powerConsumption;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product name: " + productName
                + "  power consumption: " + powerConsumption;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

those are `boolean` and you are trying to assign `int` literal to it,

you need another type of variable if you want to hold the value of those `int` literal

also `(s1 == true)` is similar to `(s1)`

Answer (score 1):

You cant assign an integer to boolean that boolean is only 1 bit of data reserve for `true` and `false`

```
this data type for simple flags that track true/false conditions. 
This data type represents one bit of information, but its "size" 
isn't something that's precisely defined.
```